# Do the magnetic fields of a current-carrying wire and a flow of electrons in the opposite direction cancel each other?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields, electricity

If a current-carrying wire with a stream of electrons moving in one direction is placed inside a stream of electrons moving in a vacuum in the opposite direction, is the magnetic field **inside** the wire cancelled by the magnetic field of the opposite flow of electrons? if not, why?

Comment: Hello~ for homework-style questions please review [these guidelines](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange). You should show as much work/reasoning as you can, and aim to distill your confusion down to a particular conceptual point.

Answer (score 0):

For a configuration with circular symmetry and with a straight wire, the field at a given radius is given by $H(r) = I(r)/(2\pi r)$ where $I(r)$ is the current that flows inside the radius $r$.  If $r$ is less than the radius of the wire then $I(r)$ is a just some portion of the full current in the wire.  The stream of electrons is outside the wire. It produces no field inside the wire if it has circular symmetry (meaning the electron current density is uniform around the circle).  
FYI, for a high frequency AC current, most of the current will flow near the surface of the wire and the field inside the wire may be very small.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. And for DC current, how can I force most of the current to flow near the surface of the wire? By using extremely low voltages? is it possible to force most of the current to flow on the surface of the wire instead of *near* the surface?

Comment: @Beom The atomic/electronic structure at interfaces and surfaces differs from the bulk.  There are material systems where the surface conductivity can be a dominant factor.  Often surface conductivity arises as a problem issue in semiconductor devices.  I don't think low voltages are any help.